# Referencing Oracle trigger old and new variables to Oracle stored procedure in parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to pass the new and old variables value to a procedure. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Below my trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "TRG_BEF_TESTE_TABELA_1"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "TESTE_TABELA_1"
REFERENCING NEW AS NOVO OLD AS VELHO
FOR EACH ROW
declare
  n_reg teste_tabela_1%rowtype;
  v_reg teste_tabela_1%rowtype;
begin
  n_reg := :new;
  v_reg := :old;
  proc_teste_tabela_1(:new);
end;
```

Below my procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_TESTE_TABELA_1(P_TABELA in teste_tabela_1%rowtype) IS
begin
end;
```

Comment: Unless `teste_tablea_1` happens to be an object table (and the procedure could be modified to take an object type and not a `%rowtype`), you can't treat the `:new` and `:old` pseudorecords as actual records.  In other words, you can't do what you want.  You could go column-by-column assigning values from `:new` and `:old` to `n_reg` and `v_reg` but that would need to get updated every time you add a new column to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a link to the Oracle docs showing how to reference the OLD/NEW pseudorecords:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18147/tdddg_triggers.htm#BABBFAGD